# jenkins windows slave scripting options

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration

I run jenkins on a linux server with a windows slave. what are my options for scripting on windows side? Is there a jenkins plugin that will let me program in Python/Go/bash and translate it on the windows slave? Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Can you explain your question? what prevents you from writing a python script and running it on your Windows slave?

Comment: assume I don't have python installed on the slave.  Can I still run python code from the master which will be executed on Jenkins slave?

Comment: The environment is set using Jenkins, there are Python plugin you can use inside the job Build section and to run it on any slave. for other languages - use google, it's pretty straight forward. If you have something specific in mind keep us updated and it'll be easier to answer your question.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand. I can still have a python interpreter running on a slave even if the slave doesn't have python installed? Is jenkins emulating python thru JVM? I have goggled this quite a bit but can't find how this works